Issue with Parallel Processing on Server Deployment Using future and promise Packages
I’ve successfully implemented parallel processing in my Shiny application using the future and promise packages, enabling non-blocking operations. Locally, everything functions flawlessly—the code that renders a .qmd file for report generation runs separately without disrupting other elements of the app.
However, after deploying the application to the server, although the app still works and returns the correct results, the part that is programmed to run in parallel and avoid interfering with other processes does not function as expected. This has led to some unexpected behavior, where the operations intended to be non-blocking seem to affect the rest of the application.
Could this issue be related to how the future package's plan is configured, for example, using future::plan(multisession)?
I implemented parallel processing using the future and promise packages in my Shiny app. Locally, the non-blocking operations work perfectly, allowing the app to render .qmd files without interfering with other processes. I expected the same behavior after deploying the app to the server. However, while the app runs and returns correct results, the parallel processing doesn't seem to function as expected, causing the operations to interfere with other parts of the app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
